# Unable to understand placeholder _ behavior in scala function application

Tags: scala, placeholder, void, currying

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.2
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val fn = (x:Int) => x+1
fn: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> val fn1 = fn _
fn1: () => Int => Int = <function0>

scala> val fn2 = fn1 _
fn2: () => () => Int => Int = <function0>
```

I don't understand why the placeholder(without a suggested type) application to a function is creating a new curried function with prefixed additional void argument.

I was expecting a compiler error or at least a warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's so due to the [uniform access principle](http://blog.knoldus.com/2012/11/21/scalaknol-understanding-uniform-access-principle/): in REPL `val` is a field of object, not a local variable. And all not `private[this]` fields are getter methods.

So your code is something like this:

```
def fn() = (x:Int) => x+1
val fn1 = fn _ // () => fn()
```

It works as expected with local variables:

```
scala> {
     |   val fn = (x:Int) => x+1
     |   val fn1 = fn _
     | }
<console>:10: error: _ must follow method; cannot follow Int => Int
                val fn1 = fn _
                          ^
```

Even though I can explain why it works this way, I still think this behavior can be considered a error.

Comment: @om-nom-nom: thank you for improvements, but not only `public` fields are getters.