# What is the analog of Category in programming

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, category-theory, type-theory

I found that there is an isomorphism between logic and programming, called [Curry-Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence), so is there any such equivalence for Category theory, which helps to understand things like Functors or Monads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! It's called [Curry–Howard–Lambek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence#Curry.E2.80.93Howard.E2.80.93Lambek_correspondence) - it maps Category objects to types and morphisms to terms. So, typed lambda (function without name) or even function may be represented as [cartesian-closed category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category), where Unite-type becomes a [terminal object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_object), set of types (or more complex structure) is [product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)), and apply+currying is [exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_object).

Comment: As I understand it, the terminal object isn't really a return type. It's the object that has an arrow from every other object going to it. Terminal objects in any category are also unique up to a unique isomorphism so you could say that, in some (important) sense, a category has "only one" terminal object (if it has one). In this category, the terminal object is the unit type. This video on initial and terminal objects is pretty good: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeQcmxM2e5I

Comment: Oh I see, thanks! I first through that `Nothing` (scala) is terminal, but then realized that it's initial type. So closed category goes from the false (Nothing) to the true (Unit).