# Scala - tupled and partially applied functions

Tags: scala

I'm fairly new to Scala and functional programming in general so I'm having a bit trouble wrapping my head around the concept of partially applied functions and function currying. There's also a pretty high chance that I'm gonna mix up some terminology, so all corrections are appreciated.

**Note**: I'm using the Scala Play framework but this is more of a Scala problem than a Play problem.

Given a function like this

```
def create(id: Long, userId: Long, label: String)
```

I get the `userId` and `label` as a `(Int, String)` tuple and the `id` as a `Long`. Basically what I'm trying to do is passing the id and the tuple to the function at the same time.

Now, I've read that passing a tuple to a function can be done something like this

```
scala> def f(a: Int, b: String) = 0
f: (a: Int, b: String)Int

scala> (f _).tupled((2, "Hello"))
res0: Int = 0
```

and that it is also possible to partially apply a function like this

```
scala> def f(a: Int, b: String) = 0
f: (a: Int, b: String)Int

scala> val ff = f(_: Int, "Hello")
ff: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> ff(2)
res1: Int = 0
```

So my initial idea was to combine these two concepts something like this

```
scala> def g(a: Long, b: Int, c: String) = 0
g: (a: Long, b: Int, c: String)Int

scala> val h = g(1, _: Int, _: String)
h: (Int, String) => Int = <function2>

scala> (h _).tupled((2, "Hello"))
```

However this results in an error

```
<console>:10: error: _ must follow method; cannot follow h.type
              (h _).tupled((1, "Hello"))
               ^
```

So my question is first of all why doesn't this work because to me this makes sense. And secondly how would I go about achieving this effect?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't abstract it twice: don't do redundand underscore to the `h` as it's already a function after partial-applying:

```
scala> def create(a: Long, b: Int, c: String) = 0
create: (a: Long, b: Int, c: String)Int

scala> val h = create(1, _: Int, _: String)
h: (Int, String) => Int = <function2>

scala> h.tupled((1, "Hello"))
res0: Int = 0
```

More deeply, `tupled` is defined on functions (means [object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) of [`Function`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.Function2), like `Int => String`), not on methods (like `def f(i: Int): String`) - so sometimes you need to convert a method to the function - it's called eta-expansion (or eta-abstraction more generally). When you do partial applying - eta-expansion is done automatically (you already have a `(Int, String) => Int`) - so you don't have to do it twice.

See [The differences between underscore usage in these scala's methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732549/the-differences-between-underscore-usage-in-these-scalas-methods), [Difference between method and function in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Looks like I still have a lot more to learn about Scala.

Comment: You're welcome! There is always a lot more to learn about Scala :)