# Scala IDE warning: "anonymous function convertible to method value"

Tags: scala, methods, alias, anonymous-function

Let's say I want to create an alias for a method:

```
def foo = bar(_)
```

This will warn that

> Anonymous function convertible to a method value

And I'm not quite sure what that's supposed to mean, because when I try what I think this might mean:

```
def foo = bar
```

I get an error

> Missing arguments for method bar(a:A)
>
> Cannot resolve reference bar with such signature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, If you want to create an "alias" for method, that's enough:

```
scala> val foo = bar(_) //val instead of def, still warning from Idea
foo: Int => Int = <function1>
```

Second, this shoud remove Idea's warning:

```
scala> val foo = bar _
foo: Int => Int
```

Actually, it's not just alias - your method becomes converted into a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala) (eta-expansion). You cant' just specify method (compile-time entity) as compiler will expect parameters - you need to convert it into a function (using underscore) first. Sometimes it's done automatically when compiler expects a function:

```
scala> val foo: Int => Int = bar
foo: Int => Int = <function1>
```

So this probably what Idea wants from you. In other cases - you have to use eta-expansion operator (`_`) explicitly.

P.S/1. `def foo = bar(_)` (`def` instead of `val`) makes no sense as it will return new (but same) function every time, `val` (or `lazy val` to be safe from `NullPointerException`) just returns it once.

P.S/2. The [difference between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732549/the-differences-between-underscore-usage-in-these-scalas-methods) `(_)` and `_` is that first is partially applied function (which does `_` eta-expansion automatically), which means that for let's say:

```
scala> def bar(a: Int, b: Int) = a
bar: (a: Int, b: Int)Int

scala> def foo = bar _
foo: (Int, Int) => Int

scala> def foo = bar(_)
<console>:8: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => bar(x$1))
       def foo = bar(_)
                     ^
<console>:8: error: not enough arguments for method bar: (a: Int, b: Int)Int.
Unspecified value parameter b.
       def foo = bar(_)
                    ^

scala> def foo = bar(_, _)
foo: (Int, Int) => Int
```

you have to specify `bar(_, _)` as there are two arguments.

Answer (score 5):

That's a suggestion from IntelliJ. If you click "More" in the suggestion, you'll see the following (sorry it's graphic, I can't copy the text):

[image]

You can either ignore or use `bar _` instead of `bar(_)`.